# How to hide a property in Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I am working in Umbraco 7 and have a requirement to hide/show a property based on some condition.

So far, I found this blog but this is for Umbraco 6 - https://dejanstojanovic.net/umbraco-cms/2014/may/hide-property-in-umbraco/

I am unable to find this class in Umbraco 7 - umbraco.presentation.LiveEditing.Utility

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just recently had to hide a property in the back office and had trouble finding a simple solution. Here is what I was able to put together from multiple sources to get the desired result.

To hide a property in the back office I am using a modified solution based on this blog post
https://www.dot-see.com/en/blog/a-simple-way-to-hide-fields-in-the-umbraco-back-end/

Here's the relevant code

In App_Plugins add the following files in a new folder called HideProperties

```
arrive.js
HidePropertiesJSOutput.ashx
package.manifest
```

**package.manifest**

```
{
  javascript: [
    "~/App_Plugins/HideProperties/arrive.js",
    "~/App_Plugins/HideProperties/HidePropertiesJsOutput.ashx"
  ]
}
```

**arrive.js**

The arrive.js file contents can be found here: https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/blob/master/src/arrive.js

**HidePropertiesJSOutput.ashx**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="HidePropertiesJsOutput" %>

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Linq;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Core.Security;
using Umbraco.Core.Models.Membership;

public class HidePropertiesJsOutput : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        IUserService userService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.UserService;
        HttpContextWrapper httpCtxWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        FormsAuthenticationTicket umbTicket = httpCtxWrapper.GetUmbracoAuthTicket();

        if (umbTicket != null)
        {
            IUser currentUser = userService.GetByUsername(umbTicket.Name);
            if (!currentUser.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == "Administrators"))
            {
                string propertyAlias = "ENTER PROPERTY ALIAS HERE"
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
                context.Response.Write("$(document).arrive(\"div[data-element='property-" + propertyAlias + "']\", function () { $(this).hide(); });\r\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This will hide a particular property in the back office for anyone not in the "Administrators" group. If you need to hide multiple you can use a for loop and potentially base the property list from a webconfig entry for easy updating as mentioned in the above blogpost link.

The only downside to this approach is that this does not remove the property from the DOM completely. Only hides it from view. Any crafty individual could potentially make the property visible by directly modifying the DOM.

To get around this we can also mark the property as Readonly dynamically as well. This will prevent any changes to values on the property from being overridden in the back office. The following code will add an event listener for SendingContentModel where you can add code to modify the content model before it's sent to the user.

You can read more about SendingContentModel and other events here: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/events/EditorModel-Events

Use the following code where applicable in your project

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Models.Membership;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Editors;
using Umbraco.Web.Models.ContentEditing;

namespace NamespaceHere
{
    public class RegisterEvents : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            EditorModelEventManager.SendingContentModel += EditorModelEventManager_SendingContentModel;
            base.ApplicationStarted(umbracoApplication, applicationContext);
        }

        private void EditorModelEventManager_SendingContentModel(HttpActionExecutedContext sender, EditorModelEventArgs<ContentItemDisplay> e)
        {
            if (e.Model.ContentTypeAlias == "ENTER CONTENT ALIAS HERE")
            {
                IUser currentUser = UmbracoContext.Current.Security.CurrentUser;
                if (!currentUser.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == "Administrators"))
                {
                    ContentPropertyDisplay propertyToHide = e.Model.Properties.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Alias == "ENTER PROPERTY ALIAS HERE");
                    propertyToHide.Readonly = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This looks for a particular ContentTypeAlias and then a particular Property Alias to hide. Again, like above, this is marking the property as readonly for users not in the "Administrators" group.

With the combination of both hiding the property on the DOM and marking the properties as Readonly your desired property values should be safe.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Backoffice Tweaking](https://our.umbraco.com/projects/collaboration/backoffice-tweaking) extension in the past, and it's worked well for this use case.

I don't know if it's still being maintained, but even if not it should be reasonably straightforward to modify the source code to get the extension working for your version of Umbraco (assuming it's 7).

Comment: I tried to use this extension, but it is throwing some errros. I am using 7.11.1

Comment: It looks like the package isn't maintained, but there is a PR for it that updates it for 7.7.x, so that might help you in this instance. https://github.com/Alain-es/BackofficeTweaking/pull/11